# Angular mat-drawer-container height (useless scrollbar)

Tags: css, angular, height, sidenav, mat-drawer

Certainly a trivial problem for a CSS expert but really infuriating for me.

Here is a stackblitz demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ezyirk?file=src%2Fexample%2Fnav-menu.html,src%2Fexample%2Fnav-menu.scss,src%2Fexample%2Fnav-menu.ts

How could I get rid off this useless scrollbar from the menu ?

I tried several CSS tricks to increase height or make the menu take the height it needs.

The only workaround I found is using "height: 100vh" in the scss file but a scrollbar for the entire page is also appearing.

I just want the menu to take the height it needs and if the menu contains lots of items exceeding the page'height then I'll accept a "global" scrollbar for the page.

Any ideas ?